# PHP Array Shows Index - But The Index is Undefined when I try to use it

Tags: php

I have a bizarre issue occuring in a csv file importer script. PHP is throwing the following error when I execute it:

```
    <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: zipcode in 
    <b>/var/www/vhosts/app.portablestoragemanager.com/httpdocs/default/models/Pricingmodel.php</b> on 
    line <b>90</b><br />
```

The reason its bizarre is in the very line before it I var_dump the data and the index is there.

```
    IMPORT<br><br>array(11) {
    ["zipcode"]=>
    string(5) "46311"
    ["rental12_onsite"]=>
    string(5) "99.99"
    ["rental16_onsite"]=>
    string(3) "179"
    ["rental20_onsite"]=>
    string(3) "209"
    ["rental12_warehouse"]=>
    string(6) "209.99"
    ["rental16_warehouse"]=>
    string(3) "189"
    ["rental20_warehouse"]=>
    string(3) "219"
    ["deliver_empty_rate"]=>
    string(2) "99"
    ["deliver_full_rate"]=>
    string(2) "99"
    ["return_empty_rate"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["return_full_rate"]=>
    string(2) "99"
```

I have tried recoding this in a variety of ways and no matter what I seem to do - I end up with the same error. The array is not an object - I have checked that and it doesnt seem to be the issue.

Here is my code that handles the file import - just assume the file is uploaded already and Im ready to process it and import to the database:

```
$toimport = fopen($destination, "r");
//get the data and the headers
$csv = array_map("str_getcsv", file($destination, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
$keys = array_shift($csv);

//close the file
fclose($toimport);

//setup our db connection
$db = Paydirt::getProvider("db/psm fees");

echo "IMPORT<br><br>";

//combine all the headers and rows into an array of associative arrays
foreach ($csv as $row)
    $impdata[] = array_combine($keys, $row);

//now iterate the data and insert / update it
for ($i = 0; $i < count($impdata); $i++) {
    echo $i ."<br>";

    $row = $impdata[$i];

    var_dump($row);
    
    $zip = $row["zipcode"]; //this is where the error notice is thrown
```

Thanks in advance for your help with this.

Rick

Comment: set a die after var_dump and the look at response . see if "zipcode"  exist in array in first place.

Comment: Is that really the output from this script? I don't see the output of `echo $i . "<br>";`

Comment: Check the header line, make sure there are no spaces in the field names.

Comment: It should be `zipcode,rental12_onsite` not `zipcode ,rental12_onsite`

Comment: @Barmar - there arent any spaces in the field names. It is the output, however, I had multiple screens open and the output I chose didnt have the $i in it. The for index ($i) does output 0.

Comment: @user122293 - I tried your suggestion of using  die(var_export($row,true)); - the data is set and outputs as array ( 'zipcode' => '46311', 'rental12_onsite' => '99.99', 'rental16_onsite' => '179', 'rental20_onsite' => '209', 'rental12_warehouse' => '209.99', 'rental16_warehouse' => '189', 'rental20_warehouse' => '219', 'deliver_empty_rate' => '99', 'deliver_full_rate' => '99', 'return_empty_rate' => '0', 'return_full_rate' => '99', 'franchiseid' => '2', )

Comment: @MediaGiantDesign maybe all $impdata does not have zipcode or try copy zipcode key from var_dumped data . maybe there is special character inside key name .

Comment: @user122293 He's adding the same keys to every element of `$impdata` with `$impdata[] = array_combine($keys, $row);`

Comment: @barmar - I think you got the answer closest - I have it fixed now. So its something with the keys and invisible characters. I started looking at the keys and then output the strlens of the keys. The zipcode key had a strlen of 10! renaming the column in the csv file didnt fix the problem either, in the end I had to create a new column and delete the first one. This fixed the zipcode key length to 7. I tried using TRIM as well but it didnt do anything. Not sure what the characters are or where they came from - but your suggestion worked.

Comment: I'll bet you have a BOM at the beginning of the file and it's being included in the first key.